# A more efficient way to work with DataSets

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, refactoring, dataset

I have the following code, repeated on each `Form`, as part of the Update process.  When the page loads the `BLL` returns a `DataSet`, say

```
_personInfo = ConnectBLL.BLL.Person.GetPerson(personID);
```

I store that `DataSet` in a `Form` level variable which I then use to check against for changes during the Validate/Update process.  I pass a row at a time(*though there is never more then one row*) to a `Function` that takes the value in a control and compares it to its corresponding column value in the `DataSet`.  If it finds it different then it sets that column = to the new value and adds the name to a `List` of what's changed.

```
// Load Person info
        using (var tmpPersonDT = tmpPersonDS.Tables[0])
        {
            if (tmpPersonDT.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in tmpPersonDT.Rows)
                {
                    CheckPersonData(row);
                }

            }
        }

// Snippet of the CheckPersonData() that is being called....
    if (!object.Equals(row["ResidencyCountyID"], lkuResidenceCounty.EditValue))
    {
        row["ResidencyCountyID"] = lkuResidenceCounty.EditValue;
        _whatChanged.Add("ResidencyCounty");
    }

if (!object.Equals(row["ResponsibilityCountyID"], lkuResponsibleCounty.EditValue))
{
    row["ResponsibilityCountyID"] = lkuResponsibleCounty.EditValue;
    _whatChanged.Add("ResponsibilityCounty");
}

if (!object.Equals(row["HispanicOriginFlag"], chkHispanic.EditValue))
{
    row["HispanicOriginFlag"] = chkHispanic.EditValue;
    _whatChanged.Add("HispanicOriginFlag");
}

if (!object.Equals(row["CitizenFlag"], chkCitizen.EditValue))
{
    row["CitizenFlag"] = chkCitizen.EditValue;
    _whatChanged.Add("CitizenFlag");
}

if (!object.Equals(row["VeteranFlag"], chkVeteran.EditValue))
{
    row["VeteranFlag"] = chkVeteran.EditValue;
    _whatChanged.Add("VeteranFlag");
}
```

**What I am trying to get an answer to, is this really the most efficient way of going about this?**

If nothing else I would like to create a function to do the comparing instead of repeating 30 times(per form varies) but I can't quite figure that out.  I thought maybe I could use row[].ItemArray but that only has the values.  I would have to *KNOW* ahead of time what order the items were in and bank on them not changing....

Am I missing something obvious for working with **DataSets/DataTables** in a **CRUD app**?

---

[***juliandewitt's*** post below is fantastic!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273197/a-more-effecient-way-to-work-with-datasets/1276314#1276314)

I just, now, need some direction on how to use that in the above. Any links that anyone can point me to would be appreciated. Even better if you can post an example.

Are there any drawbacks to using DataRows like that?

Comment: *whew* I think that's my largest answer ever :)  Seriously though, I hope between the built-in state tracking, strongly-typed DataSets and TableAdapters, and DataBinding we've opened some doors for you to find some of the RAD tools in Visual Studio as well as the power of ADO.NET.  That said, it's not a silver bullet and not a perfect system; it's a broad system that has it's flaws and limitations--but is a cornerstone of .NET 1.0 - 2.0.  .NET 3.0 and up, however, begin to lean away from ADO.NET and in 3.5 SP1 the Entity Framework begins to show.  It's all still worth knowing though!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you're doing a lot of manual labor which could be alleviated by Databinding your controls directly to your DataSet/Table.  Databinding plumbs together your datasource (your dataset/table in this case) with your UI.  When the value changes in the UI it will update the datasource.

DataBinding is a *BIG* topic that warrants researching and testing.  There are some gotcha's with databinding to a DataTable/Set (the row changes don't get commited until the current row changes, which is annoying in your case of only working with a single row at a time--but there's workarounds).

**Reworded:**
Another thing to consider is using business objects to represent the data in in your Sets/Tables.  ORM (object-relational-mappers) can handle this for you, but they are large and hugely powerful frameworks that aren't easy to master.  It's an entirely different paradigm from working with DataSet's/Tables at the UI layer and is more true to object-oriented programming.  DataSets and Tables are very good for working with tabular data, but they don't lend themselves too well to working with entities.  For example, you would work against an instance of a *Person* object with properties like *IsHispanic* and *IsCitizen* rahtner than essentially working against cells in a table (no more *myPersonTable[0]["HispanicOriginFlag"]....).

**Further:** Unrelated to your question, but relevant to CRUD operations revolving around ADO.NET: it pays to become familiar with the state-tracking built into a DataTable/DataSet.  There's lots build into ADO.NET to help make these apps easy to glue together, which would clean up *tons* of code like you've shown.

As always RAD tools have the trade-off of giving up control for productivity--but writing them off without understanding them is guaranteeing that you will spend your days writing code like you've shown.

**Even More:** To build further on my previous *Further*, when you discover the ability to combine Visual Studio's DataSet generator with the built-in rowstate tracking of DataTables, and change-tracking of DataSets it can be very easy to write a full CRUD system in little time.

Here's a quick run-down on some of the steps involved:

1. Establish your database schema
2. In Visual Studio add a new DataSet item to a project
3. Find the Server Explorer  (Under View)
4. Add your SQL Server as a Data Connection
5. Drag your table / stored proc / View into the DataSet's designer.
6. Right-click the "TableAdapter" that Visual Studio has generated for you; go to Configure
7. Configure the CRUD commands for the DataSet (the Select, Insert, Update, Delete commands)

With that you've created a *Strongly-Typed* DataSet.  The DataSet will contain a DataTable property named after the table / view / stored procedure used to generate the DataSet.  That Table property will contain strongly-typed rows, which lets you access the cells within that row as properties rather than untyped items in an object array.

So if you've generated a new DataSet named *MyDbTables*, with a table named *tblCustomer* which contains some columns like *CustomerId*, *Name*, etc... then you can work with it like this:

**This is a variety examples rolled into one, showing some of the common methods used for CRUD work--look into the methods and particulary into the TableAdapter class**

```
    public void MyDtDemo()
    {
        // A TableAdapter is used to perform the CRUD operations to sync the DataSet/Table and Database
        var myTa = new ClassLibrary4.MyDbTablesTableAdapters.tblCustomersTableAdapter();
        var myDataSet = new MyDbTables();

        // 'Fill' will execute the TableAdapter's SELECT command to populate the DataTable
        myTa.Fill(myDataSet.tblCustomers);

        // Create a new Customer, and add him to the tblCustomers table
        var newCustomer = myDataSet.tblCustomers.NewtblCustomersRow();
        newCustomer.Name = "John Smith";
        myDataSet.tblCustomers.AddtblCustomersRow(newCustomer);

        // Show the pending changes in the DataTable
        var myTableChanges = myDataSet.tblCustomers.GetChanges();

        // Or get the changes by change-state
        var myNewCustomers = myDataSet.tblCustomers.GetChanges(System.Data.DataRowState.Added);

        // Cancel the changes (if you don't want to commit them)
        myDataSet.tblCustomers.RejectChanges();

        // - Or Commit them back to the Database using the TableAdapter again
        myTa.Update(myDataSet);
    }
```

*Also, pay attention to the RejectChanges() and AcceptChanges() methods of both DataSets and DataTables.  They essentially tell your dataset that it has no changes (either by rejecting all changes, or 'commiting' all changes), but be aware that calling AcceptChanges() and then trying to do an update will have no effect--the DataSet has lost track of any changes and assumes it is an accurate reflection of the Database.*

***And even more! Here's a reworked version of your example showing some of the rowstate tracking features, assuming you've followed my steps to create strongly-typed DataSets/Tables/Rows***

```
    public void CheckRows()
    {
       MyPersonDS tmpPersonDS = new MyPersonDS();

        // Load Person info
       using (var tmpPersonDT = tmpPersonDS.PersonDT)
       {
           foreach (MyPersonRow row in tmpPersonDT.Rows)
           {
               CheckPersonData(row);
           }
       }

    }

    public void CheckPersonData(MyPersonRow row)
    {
        // If DataBinding is used, then show if the row is unchanged / modified / new...
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Row State: " + row.RowState.ToString());

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Row Changes:");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(BuildRowChangeSummary(row));

        // If not DataBound then update the strongly-types Row properties
        row.ResidencyCountyID = lkuResidencyCountyId.EditValue;


    }

    public string BuildRowChangeSummary(DataRow row)
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder result = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

        int rowColumnCount = row.Table.Columns.Count;
        for (int index = 0; index < rowColumnCount; ++index)
        {
            result.Append(string.Format("Original value of {0}: {1}\r\n", row.Table.Columns[index].ColumnName, row[index, DataRowVersion.Original]));
            result.Append(string.Format("Current  value of {0}: {1}\r\n", row.Table.Columns[index].ColumnName, row[index, DataRowVersion.Current]));

            if (index < rowColumnCount - 1) { result.Append("\r\n"); }
        }

        return result.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: See the dev's I inherited this stuff from told me to stay away from MS's databinding....

Comment: You should send those devs a nasty letter.

Comment: @Refracted: It does have some caveats and doesn't always work the way you presume--but it's the way of .NET and definately the way of WPF.  Be a champion of it and at least learn it's abilities/weaknesses

Comment: Did they give any reasons?  Other than "we don't fully understand it, and it scares us"?  Because MS's data binding works very reliably.

Comment: @Refracted: you've had to inherit their code, which (at a glance) smells.  Don't inherit their mindset without questioning their reasons

Comment: I bet these were old VB6 programmers who told you this. They may never have learned how many of VB6's problems Microsoft fixed in VB.NET 1.0.

Comment: @JohnS: Actually he was.  That's pretty good!  I am going to 'guess' that there were major issues in VB6 with this kind of thing....

Comment: @Refracted: you would have been accurate to stop at "there were major issues in VB6" :)

Comment: @Yoooder: tell me about fighting those mindsets! I just hope Refracted doesn't *have* to use an in-house developed 'framework' (many, many air quotes) evolved as a big mall of mud over time.

Comment: *ball (although for some it gets to a mall's size)

Comment: @Refracted: I had the "opportunity" to learn to recognize this pattern back when .NET first came out. I answered a lot of questions in the newsgroups back then, and saw some truly horrible messes caused by developers whose managers didn't permit them to keep up to date. A real pity as these folks should have learned in the much simpler environment of .NET 1.0.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a consistent naming convention for the properties that map to the dataset column names, reflection would make the single reusable method possible.  However, you'll need to test it to ensure that it doesn't cause a performance issue.

To do this, loop through the Columns collection from the table.  Then, for each column, use reflection to find the "matching" property on the object being compared to the row.  (You'll want to focus on the PropertyInfo class returned from obj.GetType().GetProperties(...).)

Answer (score 2):

Also the datarow automatically keeps track of changes..

```
DataRow _personInfo = ConnectBLL.BLL.Person.GetPerson(personID);  
// _personInfo.RowState = DataRowState.Unchanged
_personInfo["columnName"] = "value";
_personInfo["columnName2"] = "value2";
_personInfo.EndEdit();
// _personInfo.RowState = DataRowState.Modified
```

Now you can get the changed values by asking the rowstate and check values as follows

```
var org = fRow["columnName", DataRowVersion.Original]; 
var new = fRow["columnName",DataRowVersion.Current];
```

To detect changes you can also listen to the columnchanged event.

```
fTable.ColumnChanged += new DataColumnChangeEventHandler(delegate(object sender, DataColumnChangeEventArgs e)
{
   Console.WriteLine(e.Column.ColumnName);
}
);
```

Comment: How is it I newer new this!!!  I still need to commit the changes though(*to the DB*), correct?  I guess what I am getting at is where do `_personInfo.AcceptChanges()` and `_personInfo.BeginEdit()` come into play; If at all?

Comment: BeginEdit() to force the row into "editing mode". I guess it's also when you change a value.<br>
AcceptChanges when you have committed the changes to the database and want to start anew. (original value becomes the current value).